# Converting nvarchar to date column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a column of dates in m/d/yyyy format stored in *nvarchar(50)* data types (I inherited this...). I would like to convert these columns into *date* data types so they are correctly stored, but can't afford to accidentally drop the data in the columns.

I've tried doing this in SQL server 2008R2, using the designer to change the data type to date. This worked for my test column (kept the dates, corrected the format, etc.) but all nulls became 1900-01-01. I can live with that but it seems there's a more eloquent solution.

However, when I tried it on the real data column, I received an error:

> Unable to modify table. Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

What would be the proper way to handle this? Sorry if this is duplicate. I've been looking for an hour and haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You apparently have data somewhere in the table that SQL Server is unable to convert to date. You can find the rows with a query along these lines:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ISDATE(ColumnName) != 1
```

Obviously, you'll need to substitute TableName and ColumnName with the actual names.

Once you've identified the rows with bad data, handling it is up to you... change the data manually for each row, set them to null, whatever you feel is acceptable in this case.

Comment: That worked. I ran a query that showed me the non-dates and some 0's appeared with some Nulls. I then ran another query to update the table to replace all non-dates with NULL and then tried again. Presto! Thanks!

Comment: I have addressed how to handle, have a look at my answer. That would help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add a new column with a Date datatype then convert/copy the data over and finally delete the original column.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is

1. add another column to the table of type `DATETIME`
2. Update new column values by casting the existing column values as `DATETIME`
3. Remove the existing column

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can temporally duplicate the columns with the data type of date, with this you can run an update command to convert the varchar to datetime and store it in this new columns, when you are sure that all information is correct, you can delete the columns and rename the new ones to their original name.

I always do this when I need to ensure to not lose information on change data types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to update your date to `ISO Format (yyyymmdd)` which will gurantee to work in any server. [SQL SERVER - DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efba1/4) covers 4 possible cases of your date like `'d/m/yyyy'`,`'dd/m/yyyy'`,`'d/mm/yyyy'` & `'dd/mm/yyyy'` and update them to `ISO Format`

```
Update mytable
Set d = right(d,charindex('/',reverse(d),1)-1) + 
            right('0' + substring(d, charindex('/',d,1) + 1, charindex('/', d, charindex('/',d,1) + 1 ) - charindex('/',d,1) -1 ),2) +
            right('0' + left(d,charindex('/',d,1)-1),2)
```

***Or*** you can use this method directly in a select query as

```
Select id,convert(date,
            right(d,charindex('/',reverse(d),1)-1) + 
            right('0' + substring(d, charindex('/',d,1) + 1, charindex('/', d,
                        charindex('/',d,1) + 1 ) - charindex('/',d,1) -1 ),2) +
            right('0' + left(d,charindex('/',d,1)-1),2)
            ) correctDate
From mytable
```